# key down for ctrl + W wil trigger with ctrl + shift + W winForms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, keydown

I want to catch the keydown event so when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> it will close the form.
Currently My Code:

```
Private Sub Main_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        closeForm()
    End If
End Sub
```

The code is working fine except that when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>whatever</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (example <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>) it will also return true and execute the closeForm() method.

Any idea on how to prevent <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>whatever</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `e.KeyData` property:

```
If e.KeyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.W) Then
```

That will exclude all combinations other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.  If you wanted to do it more like what you have already then it would be:

```
If e.Control AndAlso Not e.Shift AndAlso Not e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
```

As you can see, using `e.KeyData` is much cleaner when looking for one specific key combination.